# Laravel Nova Notification Feed package is not working

Tags: laravel, pusher, laravel-nova, laravel-echo

I am using Laravel Nova for the CMS Admin panel. I am integrating live notification feed feature into my Nova application using this package, https://novapackages.com/packages/coreproc/nova-notification-feed. But it is not working.

I installed the package running this command,

```
composer require coreproc/nova-notification-feed
```

Then I migrated the required database tables

```
php artisan notifications:table

php artisan migrate
```

Then I added the required keys in the env file

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
PUSHER_APP_ID=xxxxxxx
PUSHER_APP_KEY=xxxxxxx
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=xxxxxx
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=xxx
```

I uncommented BroadcastServiceProvider line in the config/app.php as well.

Then I added the following lines in the appropriate places as mentioned in the documentation in the resources/views/vendor/nova/layout.blade.php file.

```
@include('nova-echo::meta') <!-- INCLUDE THIS LINE HERE -->

@include('nova_notification_feed::notification_feed') <!-- AND THIS LINE HERE -->
```

To make sure the Echo and the Push are working, in the resources/views/vendor/nova/layout.blade.php  file I added the following code snippet before the closing body tag.

```
<script>
        Nova.liftOff()
        Echo.channel('orders')
            .listen('OrderShipped', (e) => {
                alert('Pusher is working')
            });
    </script>
```

When I refresh the admin page, I can see that the channel is subscribed in the Pusher dashboard/ console.

[image]

But when I push notification from the Pusher console/ dashboard, it says the message has been pushed, but the event in the code is not working.

[image]

What is wrong or missing in my code?

Comment: The package you mentioned uses a modified version of Laravel Echo called [Nova Echo](https://github.com/CoreProc/nova-echo)

Comment: Yes it is bundled with the package itself already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a '.' before OrderShipped e.g.

```
<script>
        Nova.liftOff()
        Echo.channel('orders')
            .listen('.OrderShipped', (e) => {
                alert('Pusher is working')
            });
    </script>
```